# IE JQuery Trigger Fails

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page that may have parameters in the uRL. Based on the parameter I trigger a click to simulate the navigation button being clicked:

```
$('#main-nav li.filter .dropdown ul li a[rel='+dd+']').trigger('click')
```

where dd is the parameter. This works in everything bar IE.

I have read it's a security issue. If so, is there any work around for it? I would prefer not to touch the navigation set up as it's legacy code.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? `$('#main-nav li.filter .dropdown ul li a[rel='+dd+']')[0].onclick();`

Comment: Hey man, which IE version are you using, you got any demo? `:)` Hope its not IE 6!

Comment: Please set up a basic http://jsfiddle.net/ with more code. The information you've provided is not enough to track the bug down.

Comment: It's IE9 and IE8 so far.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
$('#main-nav li.filter .dropdown ul li a[rel='+dd+']').bind('click', function() {
  window.location.href = this.href;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortuantely the click actually loads content into the page. There is no actual physical page to href to.

Comment: Do you have the URL of your project so I can check it ?